# Update two objects in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

How could I update these scopes

```
$scope.name = "";
$scope.username = "";
```

Inside of one `ng-model`?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name && username"/>
```

**Update:**

I am dealing with a tricky situation that I cannot use a function to the update `$scope.username` and i'm looking for a way to do all of this just via the `ng-model` attribute.

Comment: I think you're missing something in your explanation - how you can update 2 different items (a != b) with one input value?

Comment: Thats my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here is one more approach: Using [`ngModelOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)'s `getterSetter`:

```
<input ... ng-model="getSetName" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" />

$scope.getSetName = function (name) {
  if (!arguments.length) return $scope.name;
  $scope.name = name;
  $scope.username = name;
};
```

Or a more complex example:

```
<input ... ng-model="user.fullname" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" />

$scope.user = {
  firstname: '...',
  lastname: '...',
  fullname: function (fullname) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return ((this.firstname || '') + ' ' + (this.lastname || '')).trim();
    } else {
      var parts = fullname.split(' ');
      this.firstname = parts[0];
      this.lastname = parts[1];
    }
  }
};
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/zGvgZP?editors=101)**.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way with `$parsers` and `$formatters`. You can assume that your model is a complex object, e.g. `{ name: '...', surname: '...' }`, edited in a single text box, e.g. everything before space is the `name`, everything following the first space is the `surname`.

A sample implementation, the HTML:

```
<input ng-model="data.complex" full-name="" />
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('fullName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                var tmp, result = { name: null, surname: null };
                if( value ) {
                    tmp = value.split(' ');
                    if( tmp ) {
                        if( tmp.length > 0 ) {
                            result.name = tmp.shift();
                        }
                        if( tmp.length > 0 ) {
                            result.surname = tmp.join(' ');
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                var name, surname;
                if( value ) {
                    name = value.name;
                    surname = value.surname;
                }
                if( typeof name !== 'string' ) {
                    name = '';
                }
                if( typeof surname !== 'string' ) {
                    surname = '';
                }
                return name.length > 0 ? name + ' ' + surname : surname;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uL1ors7q/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [AngularJS watcher](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for upding the other value:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch('name', function(name){
  $scope.username = name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to one scope property with `ng-model` but you could add `ng-change` to fire a function to update the other

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="updateUsername()"/>
```

Controller

```
$scope.updateUsername = function(){
   $scope.username = $scope.name;
}
```

For real time updates can switch to `ng-keyup`

This approach is less expensive than using a watch since it doesn't have to be constantly monitored and only fires on demand

Answer (score -2):

Angular two-way data binding will take care of this for you. No need to monitor change events or anything else.

In you page:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.username = $scope.name;
```

Comment: But this does not bind both values. This code is executed only once, and never again. further changes of name will not be synchronized anymore.