# AngularJS - Input value unbind when it gets edited

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem (honestly I don't know if it's intended to be like this) with a textbox in AngularJS

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/dzemk0jq/1/)

I have a

```
<input ng-value="a + b"/>
```

where I assign the concatenation of two variables.
The value is correct and updates as I edit the variables but once I edit the concat textbox (the one where I have the ngValue) it looks like it get unbinded and never updates itself anymore if the variable changes.

You can check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/dzemk0jq/1/) I made, where you can also find detailed instructions.
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but ng-value was not designed to work like this, furthermore what is the use case for implementing such a thing...when do you require 2 way binding on a expression evaluation, it is usually (allways?) one way bound i.e. read only

Comment: Totally agree with Luis; if however you need to update 2 things from 1 control, maybe take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105340/update-two-objects-in-ng-model/30105826#30105826).

Comment: ng-value is kind of display only... you should not use it like this

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos wow...that's rad I didn't even know you could do such a thing...

Comment: That's not a real answer but guesses. I'm pretty sure that when you modify the input value, it create a scoped variable and bind it to the input. Unfortunately this variable isn't the same than the result of ng-value. If you want a workaround you can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d1w4mwu9/1/ but i'm not sure that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I know I should do this in readOnly mode but unfortunately I should be able to edit the field, intercept the changed value and maybe update the initial values